# Webview App launches only one website

Tags: android, webview

I had a problem. I want to create a webview app. My java code looks like this:

```
package com.example.webview_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.scrapll.com/scrapll_m");  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

you see that I am linking to the URL www.scrapll.com/scrapll_m. It doesn't display the website. It displays only if I type in *www.scrapll.com*. I tested with other URL's (*facebook.com*, *twitter.com*, *google.com*) and I see always the same black `background`. After a while an error pops up saying that the browser stops working. It only opens *www.scrapll.com*. What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me?

My manifest code:

Yes. My manifest code is here;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webview_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webview_test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This is all my code.

Comment: Have you enabled permissions in the manifest file for Internet? That might be the problem;

Comment: I edited my post Eenvincible and yes I enabled permissions. It's strange because it opens only one website.

Comment: Which website does it open?

Comment: I tested other websites: google, twitter and facebook. All three can't be open by the browser.

Comment: What happened when you tried the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your android manifest inside the activity:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I copy and pasted it. Now the app icon on the homescreen is gone. I re-started the virtual device three times. The icon isn't appearing anymore.

Comment: No, just add those three lines inside the intent-filter that you already have; the icon should still be there. By the way, I would try creating a container to hold the webview instead of having it as the root view

Comment: same problem again. Can you help me with creating the container? I am new to Android. If you can't help no problem.

Comment: I sure can help you! Inside your main layout file, add a LinearLayout as your root layout and then inside that linear layout, you can create a FrameLayout and then inside it, add your webview like you did above. That will let the webview take a given amount of space instead of the whole view

Comment: Thank you, it works. But still webview isn't working. I enabled Javascript. But every website with javascript isn't working in my webview. Is this because I don't use WebViewClient? Can you see what is wrong in my code above

Comment: You only need a webViewClient if you want to override its methods like when a page starts loading etc/ and no, I cannot see what is wrong.I don't know what will happen if you remove the http:// protocol portion